# Which one is better to parse XML in php?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a web service which returns data in xml format. The xml result is so complicated and have lot of attributes attached to each tag. I need only part of it i.e only some attributes in the entire xml

I have tried two approaches in parsing it.

1. XPATH using simpleXMLELEMENT
2. json_encode the xml string and json_decode the same

My question is: Which one is better in terms of performance?

I get the data i want using both approaches mentioned above. Any other better approach is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're saying, you want to know if it is faster to use SimpleXML, or to JSON encode/decode **and** use SimpleXML?

Answer (score 1):

forgetting xml all together and using JSON instead is a much lighter weight way to transport data. parsing may be another story however depending.

I'm not sure what the heck you mean by json decoding the xml. how exactly is this expected to work? you can only json decode json data, not xml data.

as for parsing xml... simplexml will load the entire xml document into memory. you could leverage XMLReader to parse the xml node by node and stop when you find the data you are looking for. harder to code, but probably the fastest depending.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php

you may have to roll a few versions and do some actual benchmarking for your particular situation however.